# Upload pdf files to Sharepoint using rest API

Tags: swift

My requirement is i want the user to fetch attachment from icloud drive and submit.once the user has submitted the attachment document(pdf,word,ppt) has to get uploaded to sharepoint.

tried converting file to nsdata and pass it to json key as an array

```
let fileURL = attachment
print("FilePath: \(fileURL!.path)")
var filemgr: FileManager?

filemgr = FileManager.default

if filemgr!.fileExists(atPath: fileURL!.path) {
    print("File exists")
} else {
    print("File not found")
}

let databuffer = filemgr!.contents(atPath: fileURL!.path)

var buffer = [UInt8](databuffer!)

buffer[0] = buffer[0] + UInt8(1)
print(buffer)

let contentDictionary = buffer

print(contentDictionary)
var jsonData: Data? = nil
do {
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: contentDictionary , options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch {
}
```

Expected : the file which has uploaded should open

Actual : getting error as "failed to load pdf doc"

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to serialize binary file into JSON?

Comment: yes ..... suggest me the best way to pass a file

Comment: As far as I know you cannot serialize this type of data. You can only serialize Swift data types into JSON.

Comment: yes thanks! when i unserialized the data it worked fine...